# Getting the wrong answer using Tensorflow's Premade Estimator for Linear Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am new to stack overflow and tensorflow.  I was trying to redo the simple linear regression from Introduction to Machine Learning (Andrew Ng's Coursera class) using the premade linear regression estimator.

I've coded the linear regression model in python using numpy and scikit-learn and successfully found the model parameters [theta0, theta1] = [-3.6303, 1.1664].  This was done with both the normal equation and regular gradient descent.

I have not been able to use Tensorflow's premade estimator for Linear Regression to produce the same results.  I'm using the basic approach identified in the Google Machine Learning Crash Course -- First Steps with TensorFlow (and also here: https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/machine-learning-part-iv-efecd2f61f35).

I put the data here: https://github.com/ChristianHaeuber/TensorFlowData

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import math

from IPython import display
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format

data = pd.read_csv('ex1data1.txt')

batch = data.shape[0]

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('population')]

targets = data['profit']

my_optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)

linear_regressor = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
        feature_columns=feature_columns,
        optimizer=my_optimizer
        )

def input_fn(ft, t, batch=1, shuffle=True, epochs=None):
    ft = {k:np.array(v) for k,v in dict(ft).items()}
    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((ft, t))
    ds = ds.batch(batch).repeat(epochs)

    if shuffle:
        ds=ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)

    ft, lb = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    return ft, lb

ft = data[['population']]
input_fn_1 = lambda: input_fn(ft, targets)

linear_regressor.train(
        input_fn = input_fn_1,
        steps=1
        )

input_fn_2 = lambda: input_fn(ft, targets, shuffle=False, epochs=1)

p = linear_regressor.predict(input_fn = input_fn_2)

p = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in p])

mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(p, targets)

print("MSE: %0.3f" % mse)

print("Bias Weight: %0.3f" % 
      linear_regressor.get_variable_value('linear/linear_model/bias_weights').flatten())
print("Weight %0.3f" % 
      linear_regressor.get_variable_value('linear/linear_model/population/weights').flatten())
```

Answer (score 0):

The Introduction to Machine Learning course did a batch gradient descent using all of the training examples at each iteration and then used multiple iterations to converge.  The code above would only use one training example (batch=1) and the number of iterations (steps) is forever (based on tf.estimator.LinearRegressor.train documentation).

I was able to replicate the results from the Introduction to Machine Learning class with a couple of changes.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import math
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format

def my_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size=1, num_epochs=None):

    features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in         
                dict(features).items()}

    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features,labels))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

    features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    return features, labels

ex1_data_df = pd.read_csv('ex1data1.txt')

features = ex1_data_df['population']
my_features = ex1_data_df[['population']]
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('population')]
labels = ex1_data_df['profit']

my_optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)

linear_regressor = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
        feature_columns = feature_columns,
        optimizer=my_optimizer)

_ = linear_regressor.train(
        input_fn = lambda:my_input_fn(my_features, labels, 
                                      batch_size=ex1_data_df.shape[0]), 
        steps=2000
        )

predictions = linear_regressor.predict(
        input_fn=lambda:my_input_fn(my_features,labels,
                                    batch_size=1,num_epochs=1)
        )

predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in     predictions])

mean_squared_error = metrics.mean_squared_error(predictions, labels)
print("Mean Squared Error (on training data):     {}".format(mean_squared_error))

weight =     linear_regressor.get_variable_value('linear/linear_model/population/weights')
bias = linear_regressor.get_variable_value('linear/linear_model/bias_weights')
print("Feature weight: {0}\t Bias weight: {1}".format(weight, bias))
```